# Faulty application of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to $f(x) = 0$ for $x\ne 0$, $f(0)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

I think I have given a fallacious proof but I can't seem to find what is wrong with it.

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has the property that $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}. \int_a^b f(t)dt = b - a$. Consider the following "proof" that f(x) = 1. Define $g(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$. Then from above we know g(x) = x. Further by the fundamental theorem of calculus $g'(x) = f(x) = 1$.
But then consider $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $x=0$} \\ 1 & \text{if $ x \not = 0$}\end{cases}$$
Doesn't this function have the above property?

Comment: Is $f$ a continuous function in your problem?
Otherwise $f=1$ almost everywhere, i.e. the set where $f$ is not $1$ has measure 0.

Comment: Why is $g$ differentiable?

Comment: Uh, as I understand it, the $f$ in the hypothesis and the $f$ you have are different.

Comment: @Santiage Canez, is it not the case that if $f$ is Riemann integrable and $g(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$ then $g$ is differentiable and in particular $g'(x) = f(x)$?

Comment: [Not exactly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements); yet, it will be here [differentiable almost everywhere.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem#Statement)

Comment: To answer your question: it is true that if $f$ is R. integrable and $g(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$ then $g$ is differentiable, but it is not true that $g'(x)=f(x)$.  The most common hypothesis used to ensure that $g'(x)=f(x)$ is that $f$ is a *continuous* function.  Your example is not continuous, and provides a counterexample to your claim.

Comment: @Santiago $ g (x)=x $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus states that:

> If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ (say) is a **continuous** function, and we define:
>
> $$
> F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt
> $$
>
> then $F'(x)=f(x)$.

I have put one of the words in the statement in **bold**, which is the clue to seeing why the FTC does not apply to your function.  Indeed, the example you provide show why the hypothesis in bold is necessary to derive the FTC.

Comment: This is certainly true if one insists on that statement of the fundamental theorem; nevertheless, many texts use the weaker hypothesis that $f$ just has to be Riemann integrable (and therefore can have jump discontinuities,say). It is possible to explain the situation without disqualifying it on technical grounds.

Comment: That weaker hypothesis invalidates the theorem, as the example given in the question shows.  You can weaken the hypothesis 'continuous' a bit by allowing jump discontinuities, but not to all Riemann integrable functions.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 Yes, nobody disagreed that it invalidates the weak statement of this theorem that only uses continuity. But according to Royden, Wikipedia, and Stein & Shackarchi, it *is* valid for integrable $f$. Continuity is just a simple way to avoid the more advanced discussion which entails functions of bounded variation.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to keep in mind here is that Riemann integrals (and Lebesgue integrals) don't really operate on measurable functions, they operate on *equivalence classes* of functions, where the equivalence relation is "equal except on a set of measure zero."

This is a case of two functions which are not *identical*, but they differ on a set of measure zero. As such, the integral can't distinguish between them.

You can find the following theorem on page 126 of the 4th edition of Royden's *Real Analysis*:

[image]

*Almost all* needs to be included because your example shows a case where the left and right sides are not equal *everywhere*.

Comment: This is what my gut is telling me, but it's been a long time since I've thought about it. Hopefully I'm not dreadfully wrong, but if I am, this solution will disappear.